# Return codes for int main - is there a cap?

Tags: c++, linux, program-entry-point, exit-code

I have been playing around with return codes today for which I created a for loop in bash to test it out:

```
for RC in {1..300}
do
    echo "int main(void) { return $RC; }" > test.cpp
    g++ test.cpp -o test
    ./test
    echo $?
done
```

However after reaching 255 it seems to begin from 0 again. Why is that?

EG:

```
252
253
254
255
0
1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because **return codes** in POSIX-compliant systems are limited to the range [0-255].

With regard to Bash, [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Exit-Status) is a handy reference on exit statuses.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the limited range is fine because the exit code should only ever indicate success/failure. It should never be used to return data. Data should instead be written to stdout, and the exit code should be 0 if the program succeeded.

Comment: @thatotherguy: that's a very platform-specific view, and for the non-use of exit-code, disputable even as a platform-specific view. the advice to use `stdout` for error reporting is just extremely badm, misleading readers into doing the entirely Wrong Thing. use `stderr` or C++ `std::cerr` or `std::wcerr`, anyway use the OS error stream, for error reports; that's what it's there *for*.

Comment: I agree @thatotherguy, it should only indicate success/failure. I was not sure why did that. However as John Kugelman edited in, this is unfortunately a duplicated question. I will search better next time.

Comment: Note that the selected answer of the duplicate conflates C++ requirements with requirements of the bash shell, and fails to discuss limitations on C++ `main` return values on other platforms then Unix-land. I.e. it's not just platform-specific but command interpreter specific. I added a short more general answer there, but there's no practical way to get the OP of an old question to change the selection of "solution".

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf No one suggested using stdout for error reporting. How do you dispute using the exit code only for success or failure status on a Unix-like system?

Comment: @thatotherguy: quoting you, " Data should instead be written to stdout". I.e. ***you*** suggested it. For proper use of exit codes in Unix-land, look up the documentation.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If you consider "error reporting" to be a subset of "data", you can make that point instead. If you thought "data" specifically meant "error reporting", I don't know what to say. As for [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html), it only talks about using exit code for status. Are you disputing it because it's technically possible to write a userland in which exit code isn't interpretted canonically?

Comment: @thatotherguy: mumble bumble stumble not very meaningful your writing is. it's certainly *fine* if you're now backing down. but you're adding question with the very questionable assumption that i'm disputing a part of the documentation that i pointed you to. i don't know, it sounds like rubbish. anyway, take a look at (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-320/include/sysexits.h). think about why such standardization attempt was made. do you think that list was made because exit codes are only used as binary success/failure indication?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Hah, I feel the same way. I don't think we'd disagree if we talked in code instead of English :)